# Dynamically add editextext to android app and retrieve values

Tags: android

I am building an app where the users can add editText dynamically so that I can send those values into my database. Almost all websites I have come across only add views but they don't retrieve the values.

Comment: Please elaborate your question properly.

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: its a new activity i am adding to my app and this activity must have a button that a user can click on inorder to generate edittext dynamically so that i can later retrieve those values and send them into my database.

Comment: Solution 1-
Along with adding the view in layout you need to maintain it's instance also that you can easily do by adding it in a list and when you need to retrieve the value just query the instance from the list and find the value.

Solution 2-
Add the tag to your edittext before adding it in the view by using setTag method (hint you can use postion to tag) and then base on the tag added you can find the exact view and get the data.

Comment: @ Shivam Yadav okay Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While add view in you set tag edittext useing below method

```
LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewWithTag("layout1");
```

Also for getting text from the edittext you can use below code

```
EditText etText = (LinearLayout)findViewWithTag(“Tag1”);
String text=etText.getText().ToString();
```

Comment: @joe sure please check and let me know in case further assistance required.

Comment: @Mr.Awesome so sorry something came up. I will try it today and get back to you.